# mlflow run git-uri clone to specific directory

Tags: python-3.x, mlflow, mlops

I am using mlflow run with a GitHub uri.

When I run using the below command

```
mlflow run <git-uri>
```

The command sets up a conda environment and then *clones the Git repo into a **temp** directory, But I need it setup in a **specific** directory*

I checked the entire document, but I can't find it. Is there no such option to do so in one shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-local URIs, MLflow uses the Python's `tempfile.mkdtemp` function ([source code](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/1c43176cefb5531fbb243975b9c8c5bfb9775e66/mlflow/projects/utils.py#L140)), that creates the temporary directory.  You may have some control over it by setting the `TMPDIR` environment variable as described in [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp) (it lists `TMP` & `TEMP` as well, but they didn't work for me on MacOS) - but it will set only "base path" for temporary directories and files, the directory/file names are still will be random.

Comment: Got it, this will be helpful. Thank you soo much for doing the tedious job of going through the code for it. Much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for edit and fixing the typo in variable name

Comment: Sure, No problem. :)